# how to deal with bool return type?

Tags: c

my code is this:

```
 bool lookup(...)
      { 
         for(...)
           if(...)
             {           
               if (...)
               {
               ...
               return true;
               }
               else
               {
               return false;
               }
             }
             else
             {
             return false;
             }   
      }
```

Everything is going fine but 1 error occurs. error is  "error: control may reach end of non-void function".
Please tell me how do I resolve this error?

Comment: 1- it will help you to format your code so that you can see the braces lined up to see where everything is paired.   2- what are you building this in?  Isn't there a debugger that you can follow with???  3- sounds like homework, asking how to resolve this from a group of experts would be "cheating" no?  why don't you come with what you have tried and what you believe and ask for help going in the right direction rather than a complete resolution.

Comment: you aren't returning anything if your first "if" statement is false for all entries in your for loop.  You'd need a final return false statement after your for loop ends.  That's causing the error here.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
bool lookup(string s)
{
    bool output = false;

    for (...)
    {
         if (...)
         {
              output = true;
              break;
         }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: i did this but now segmentation fault occured

Comment: Segmentation faults happen when you're trying to access memory you're not supposed to be accessing. Make sure that you're not trying to access characters of string s that are <0 or >=length.

Answer (score 1):

What value do you want returned if the `for` loop ends? Presumably you should `return false` if nothing is found.

Comment: i want to return false if nothing is found

Comment: @swati Well in that case, put a `return false` immediately after your loop, as the last line in your function.

Comment: if i will do this it will take false as return every time whether true or false

Comment: when i mentioned a return, then it should come out of for loop and return. why should i mention another return outside for??

Comment: @swati No, your function will return whatever you told it to return. So if the `return true` is triggered by your conditional, then your function will return true.

Comment: @swati The reason for having a `return` statement outside of the loop is that the compiler itself cannot prove that you will return from the function for everything possible path the loop may take. That is, **yo** may know that the loop will always hit a return, but the **compiler** does not, and therefore the compiler is asking you to put-in a fail-safe return statement for your function should the loop terminate without hitting a `return`.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means the compiler is detecting that your code in a function that has a return type (in this case, bool) reaches a place where it will not return anywhere.

In this case, you should add a return after the for loop (eg. return false)

Comment: if i will do this it will take false as return every time whether true or false

Comment: @swati No it won't if you have return true in the correct places. Mike Trusov has supplied a much more elegant solution though, you should try his.